# In how many ways can you choose 3 pairs from a group of 50 persons?

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried to solve the following problem:
In how many ways can you choose 3 pairs from a group of 50 persons?

My attempt:

You first have a group of 50 persons to choose from, you want to take 2 elements from the group of 50 (50 choose 2) and then you have a group of 48 of which you choose 2 (48 choose 2) and so on. 
The multiplication principle gives you the following since all of these are dependent scenarios.

$\binom{50}{2}*\binom{48}{2}*\binom{46}{2}$=1548078480

Is this correct? 
Thanks beforehand

Comment: I think you have to divide for $3!$. Because the order of the choice are not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer should be

$$\binom{50}{2}\binom{48}{2}\binom{46}{2}\div 3!=238360500$$

Choosing $(A,B),(C,D),(E,F)$ is the same as  $(C,D),(E,F),(A,B)$, etc.

Comment: Or combinations of 50 taken by 6, 50!/(44!*6!), multiplied by 15 (5*3*1); ie how many ways you can select the six from the fifty times how many ways you can arrange the six into pairs